# Restlet Image Upload not getting ImageInfo

Tags: java, ajax, restlet, image-upload

I currently have a simple HTML form with AJAX call to Restlet Resource to upload a image.

When I do the Sanselon.getImageInfo I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.sanselan.ImageReadException: Couldn't read magic numbers to guess format.
        at org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan.guessFormat(Sanselan.java:147)
        at org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan.getImageParser(Sanselan.java:596)
        ....
```

I'm at a loss.  I'm getting the file name.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is my html:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<table>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2">File Upload</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Select File </th>
  <td><input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<script>
$("form").submit(function(evt){  
    evt.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/fileupload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });

  return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following Is my resource Post with restlet:

```
@Post
public Representation accept(Representation entity) throws Exception {
    Representation result = null;
    if (entity != null) {
        if (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.equals(entity.getMediaType(), true)) {
            // 1/ Create a factory for disk-based file items
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            factory.setSizeThreshold(1000240);

            // 2/ Create a new file upload handler based on the Restlet
            // FileUpload extension that will parse Restlet requests and
            // generates FileItems.
            RestletFileUpload upload = new RestletFileUpload(factory);

            // 3/ Request is parsed by the handler which generates a
            // list of FileItems
            FileItemIterator fileIterator = upload.getItemIterator(entity);

            //FileWriter fstream = null;

            // Process only the uploaded item called "fileToUpload"
            // and return back
            boolean found = false;
            while (fileIterator.hasNext() && !found) {
                FileItemStream fi = fileIterator.next();
                if (fi.getFieldName().equals("fileToUpload")) {
                    found = true;
                    // consume the stream immediately, otherwise the stream
                    // will be closed.
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("media type: ");
                    sb.append(fi.getContentType()).append("\n");
                    sb.append("file name : ");
                    sb.append(fi.getName()).append("\n");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(fi.openStream()));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    result = new StringRepresentation(sb.toString(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                    ImageInfo imageInfo =        Sanselan.getImageInfo(fi.openStream(), fi.getName());
                    System.out.println(imageInfo);
                    ImageStatus imageStatus = fileUploadService.saveImage(fi);

                }
            }
        } else {
            // POST request with no entity.
            setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is failing on the following line of code:

```
ImageInfo imageInfo = Sanselan.getImageInfo(fi.openStream(), fi.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is on the point to consume the stream of the uploaded stream three times:

- the first time by completing a StringBuilder (which is totally useless in your case, because an image file is binary stuff, not character-based stuff),
- the second time by getting the image info using sanselan,
- the third time by saving the image using the fileUploadService

As we can only read the socket once, there is an issue.
Can you remove the first block of code? This will allow you to get the ImageInfo, I think. I'm a little bit more reserved regarding the "save" operation, I think it will fail.